# iOS Push Notification debugging

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

So I'm writing an app in Swift that will receive push notifications.  I've been using the tutorial on Wenderlich's site as a guide, as I've never done PN before.  I've had to go beyond that to try and figure this out though.  Bottom line, no notifications show up on the phone.  Per the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) I've installed the PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig on my device.  Looking through the logs, I see a lot of reference to what looks like registration from my app, like the following:

```
08/18/15 21:48:54 SpringBoard[43] APSConnection: <APSConnection: 0x18ce8010> requestTokenForTopic: com.uselessappsinc.yakko identifier (null)
```

and more interesting:

```
08/18/15 22:04:16 SpringBoard[43] APSConnection: <APSConnection: 0x18ce8010> setEnabledTopics (
"com.uselessappsinc.yakko") ignoredTopics () opportunisticTopics () sendToDaemon: YES
```

this.  I'm not sure, but this seems to say that although registered, I'm not actually registered to receive any type of notification.

This is the code I'm using:

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Sound, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

The crux of it is I don't know where to go from here.  It seems that my phone knows the app is registered for notifications, but I'm not clear that they are arriving.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you implemented the callback on UIAppDelegate for receiving the device token?

Comment: yes, i get my token just fine.  that is what i used to put into the php script that sends off the push notification to apple.

Comment: Two things I recommend trying: make sure you implement didReceiveRemoteNotification on UIappdelegate to make a uialertview popup when it gets a notification. If the app is in the foreground then thenotification will not be displayed by iOS and instead will be delivered to this method. second make sure you can get the error response from apple by sending a deliberately invalid token to them and getting the invalid token error. If you can't this probably means you are not doing error handling correctly.

Comment: when i send an invalid token, i'm still getting a success message back.  this is how it is sent:  // Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

Comment: and I do have didReceiveRemoteNotification implemented.

Comment: It looks like I need to find another way to send a test message.

Comment: Thought i found it.  was sending to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com.  that is for development, drop the sandbox for production, which is what my certificates are.  No dice though, still not coming through.